# Popcorn with truffle oil/salt

Tags: mold, popcorn

I bought (and ate) popcorn made with truffle oil and truffle salt.  I noticed one kernel had a small, moldy spot on it and I tossed it aside and continued eating because the rest of the popcorn looked fine.  As I was eating I did notice two other kernels with the same, small, dark green spots but finished the bag anyway! Now I'm worried that I ate something that is going to make me seriously ill - spores or...????  I don't know what I was thinking!!!!  Should I have thrown the bag out?  Really worried.

Answer (score 1):

**Most molds are harmless**, especially if you heated it properly which you should have had done when you popped the kernels. Don't worry and **relax** first of all. If you do feel sick or if it would put you at ease then go see a medical professional and explain what happened. But overall you should be fine.

P.S. Oils like truffle oil lose their scent, aroma and overall taste when heated too high so most things like truffle popcorn go to waste; just get truffle oil and add it to popped popcorn. Be sure to see that the oil is mainly truffle. (most truffle oils have lots of additives.)

**If you meant pre-popped...**
Again, most molds are fine and it's good that you threw away any odd bits.